# Pen testing - How to use credentials without remote desktop?

Tags: windows, penetration-test

I'm a junior penetration tester, working in a place that does not give much guidance and I kind of just had to dive in. I'm pretty good, in that I can normally still obtain domain admin on networks I audit, as well as numerous other vulnerabilities. There is still a lot I don't know, that I am trying to learn to be a better tester.

One thing in particular is, what good are user credentials if I can't log on to other machines via remote desktop?

I had thought logging on to other machines to try and get local admin to access hashes and other such stuff is a big part of the process. But if remote desktop is not enabled or logins restricted to certain users, how can you use user credentials to still do this?

Comment: If you gain access through other means, then you can pivot?

Comment: @schroeder That's my question I guess, elaborate on 'other means'? At the moment I stick to looking to machines I can use founds credentials to log on to.

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that. You have the entire spectrum of exposed services that each could provide potential access. Or soceng your way in, or drop a rogue device on the network, or ...

Comment: I'm not talking about socenging or anything like that. Specifically, what ways are there to access a workstation machine with RDP disabled? No special services, network services etc, just default Windows workstation/desktop services. psexec?

Comment: From an external network or from inside the same network?

Comment: Inside the same network. Captured hash via NTLM/LLMNR poisoning and cracked it with jon.

Comment: Then there are lots of ways of gaining access without RDP. Powershell, psexec, shared drives, etc.

Comment: Elaborating on those methods would be a good answer, then. FWIW I've tried shared drives and powershell, tried psexec last time I had a chance too and it failed, although can't remember why.

Comment: Note that if you captured the  NTLM/LLMNR hash then you can pass the hash everywhere

Comment: Yes, but I need a service that I can pass the hash to, which can be harder to find.

Comment: WinRM, WMI, SMB, web applications with credential reuse. You cannot say just a workstation because my default workstation setup is not the same across each org. What services do they have running on the default work station?

Comment: @McMatty, I've done about 50 assessments so far, and so far have not found any workstations running web services or anything of the sort. Just standard Windows desktop services, no special applications or anything.

Comment: @schroeder You need to have admin credentials to use `psexec`. Also `Powershell` isn't remote by default.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to remote desktop (and PowerShell remoting, as @JoeM mentioned), credentials can be used for lots of things.

- Accessing network shares or other resources over SMB
- Access other services that are protected by Windows authentication (for example, internal web apps, SharePoint, etc.)
- Logging into a user's mailbox (for example, on Exchange) to access the user's email and messaging
- Using Windows remote management apps (may Windows command-line apps, such as `schtasks.exe` will accept a machine name and credentials)
- Using Management Console snapins (many of the "Computer Management" tools can connect to remote machines)
- Using Sysinternals `psexec.exe` tool
- Using WMI (Windows Management Infrastructure)
- Using [SSH](https://www.howtogeek.com/336775/how-to-enable-and-use-windows-10s-built-in-ssh-commands/) (if it has been enabled)
- Logging into a VPN (if only Windows creds are required or you can access the other creds needed)

Comment: I don't remember the detail (I've been meaning to ask this question for a while) but I remember psexec failing last time I tried. Does it have to be explicitly enabled? WMI, management console and windows remote management apps are stuff I have to look into more, thanks!

Comment: SMBMap across all the hosts you have using the credentials you have. Do any of the credentials have access to $Admin on these machines? If yes then you can use psexec on it.

Comment: Psexec will fail on windows 7 because machines need to have specific entries in their registry

Comment: Also, if you know creds, you can do what psexsc do manually. First you use net use to mount share, then you upload file to that share, make a service with that file and wait for connection or whatever you wanna do

Answer (score 0):

You could do a nmap scan of the host, find what ports are listening and try to authenticate to those services (provided they allow authentication).

If you are lucky, for example you discover port 1433 is open, then you attempt to use a MS SQL Server client to authenticate.

Maybe 5985 and 5986 are open, this allows for remote PowerShell commands to be run.

This follows the basic recon, then attack method.

Comment: In practice I have not found any useful services listening on the workstations themselves. Shares did not have anything interesting or were open without requiring auth anyway, no remote powershell etc...just remote desktop with user logins disabled. I remember trying psexec and it failing...does it need to be enabled, i.e. is it disabled by default?

Comment: Hey Jake - That is good and bad :) Sounds like you have been finding some environments with decent security. But where I find things like that are in large enterprises that have been around a while. They may have purchased an appliance from a vendor, or had professional services install a stack of services, never to revisit and secure. Or past admins turned features on to automate, but never secured them.  Good luck!

Answer (score -3):

Social engineering:

Send an email with "here are your credentials. I will tell your boss that you are a vulnerability to the company unless you follow the instructions in the attached document". And the document is an infected .doc or .pdf.

Comment: In this example, the credentials are not necessary or important. It might be far more interesting if the infected document leveraged the credentials to gain access to the device or network. But from a pentesting perspective, intentionally infecting machines tends to be out of scope.